# how to refresh google maps on the same div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have an experiment to create multiple card with bootstrap, where each card has a button to show simple google maps inside panel-collapse on bootstrap modal.

on html side, every button has data attribute to passing longitude and latitude data to be rendered on the same modal div.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-frame="iframe" data-target="#workshopModal" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1KOBVZMJkgY" data-lat="-6.349931" data-lng="106.899435" >Detail</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-frame="iframe" data-target="#workshopModal" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W3qoutZ_mEs" data-lat="-7.349931" data-lng="107.899435" >Detail</a>
```

problem :

When i'm clicking on first card detail button, lat and lng parameter correctly parsed and maps shown as what i'm expected.

But when i'm click another detail button, lat and lng parameter doesn't change and still showing previous maps with previous lat and lng value.

I'm trying to submit another value and debug it by alerting lat, lng and videoSRC value. videoSRC value is changing, but not for lat and lng.

Please help me to fix this issue, your help is highly appreciated

Below is JQuery sample code from my webpage :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function initialize(lat,lng) {
        var mapProp = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom:15,
          scrollwheel:false,
          draggable:false,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          var_infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });*/
      }




      function loadingModal(){
        var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
        trigger.click(function() {
          var theFrame = $(this).data( "frame" );
          var theModal = $(this).data( "target" );

          var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-lng"));
          videoSRC = $(this).attr( "data-theVideo" );

          $("[id*=workshopModal]").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("[id*=workshopModal] "+ theFrame).removeAttr('src');
            //google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'bounds_changed');
            $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
            $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('hide');
          });

          $("#workshopModal").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
            alert(lat+' '+lng+' '+videoSRC);
            initialize(lat,lng);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
          });


        });
      }

      loadingModal();
    });
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with working example?

Comment: I'm sorry for my silly question , i've found the solution and it is pretty simple, just remove var from var lat and var lng  and it's work :))